Python Flask: Chatbot and managing sessions
I am making a chatbot and will be hosting it online and naturally I need to use flask sessions (or something similar) in order to keep chat context different for different users. For some reason, when I just call the API URL in my browser window, the sessions are tracked properly. However when I use the chatbot interface to call the API URL, the server thinks that every request is a new session.
I simplified the question route into just being a counter as shown below:
@app.route('/question/\<q\>')

def answer(q):

    session['counter'] = session.get('counter', 0) + 1
    print(session['counter'])
    session.modified = True
    return "done"

Here is the javascript code that calls this route:
const generateResponse = (incomingChatLi) => {
    const API_URL = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/question/" + encodeURIComponent(userMessage);
    const messageElement = incomingChatLi.querySelector("p");

    fetch(API_URL,{
        method:'GET',
        credentials:'include'
    }).then(response => response.text()).then(data =>{
        messageElement.textContent = data;
        chatbox.scrollTo(0,chatbox.scrollHeight);
    }).catch(error => {
        console.error('Error:',error)
        messageElement.textContent = "Error fetching response";
        messageElement.classList.add("error");
    });

}

Does anyone know why calling the url "http://127.0.0.1:5000/question/hi" for example increases the counter everytime I make a request, but when I call the same URL in JavaScript the **counter keeps returning 1 every time and at every request
** when it should update?
